# Enqueuing JMS message directly into a Oracle persisent store

Tags: oracle, jms, weblogic

Is there a way to enqueue a JMS message into an Oracle table that is used as a persistent store for WebLogic JMS Server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a JMS Server, it will ask you to configure a persistent store.  If you configure and use a JDBCStore (vs. a FileStore) it will ask for a database connection and create a table there called WL_Store, which it will use to store messages.

Are you asking if you can manually write a message into the WL_Store table?

Comment: Yes - I would like to manually insert message to WLStore table, you can do it with AQ http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14257/aq_opers.htm#i1005596 and I am looking for the same way of inserting them into the queue table.

Comment: In that case I don't know.  (Doing so would be very unwise anyway, for many reasons)

Answer (score 0):

You have yourself mentioned AQ, why not continue using AQ and configure WLS to enable consumption messages from AQ itself.

Its not advisable to store messages into the JMS JDBC store. JMS JDBC Store not only stores the messages by a bunch of extra information like message state, destination information and so on which wont be straight forward to push programatically.

Oracle hasnt provided a way to do this in their documentation anyways.